# When forward using MXNet, how to do with varying 'batch size' in data_shapes?

Tags: mxnet

Hi，I have a question that, how can I make predict with unfixed input data?  I will try to describe in detail clear:
  I use MTCNN for face detection(it's ok unfamiliar with that), and it employs 3 networks: PNet, RNet, ONet. PNet detects a mass of proposal face bounding boxes, then these boxes are coarse-to-fine by the rest net one after another, finally get precise face bbox(s). When taking an image as input to PNet, image's size is unfixed, and the output proposal box number from PNet is also unfixed, so as RNet, ONet. Reference to another MTCNN code I set a large data_shapes(e.g., image size, batch size) when I bind the module, and initialize all to zero，then make predict. That works though, Isn't that a redundant calculation? (Question 1)

## PNet:

```
max_img_w=1000
max_img_h=1000
sym, arg_params, aux_params = mx.model.load_checkpoint(‘det1’, 0)
self.PNets = mx.mod.Module(symbol=sym, context=ctx,label_names=None)
self.PNets.bind(data_shapes=[(‘data’, (1, 3, max_img_w, max_img_h))],for_training=False)
self.PNets.set_params(arg_params,aux_params)
```

## RNet

```
sym, arg_params, aux_params = mx.model.load_checkpoint(‘det2’, 0)
self.RNet = mx.mod.Module(symbol=sym, context=ctx,label_names=None)
self.RNet.bind(data_shapes=[(‘data’, (2048,3, 24, 24))],for_training=False)
self.RNet.set_params(arg_params,aux_params,allow_missing=True)
```

## ONet

```
sym, arg_params, aux_params = mx.model.load_checkpoint(‘det3’, 0)
self.ONet = mx.mod.Module(symbol=sym, context=ctx,label_names=None)
self.ONet.bind(data_shapes=[(‘data’, (256, 3, 48, 48))],for_training=False)
self.ONet.set_params(arg_params,aux_params,allow_missing=True)
```

And I try mx.mod.Module.reshape before predict, which will adjust data'shape according to last network's output, but I get this error:(Question 2)
AssertionError: Shape of unspecified array arg:prob1_label changed. This can cause the new executor to not share parameters with the old one. Please check for error in the network. If this is intended, set partial_shaping=True to suppress this warning.

One more thing is that The MTCNN code (https://github.com/pangyupo/mxnet_mtcnn_face_detection) primary use deprecated function to load models:

```
self.PNet = mx.model.FeedForward.load(‘det1’,0)
```

One single line to work with arbitrary data_shapes, why this function be deprecated..?(Question 3)
I found a little difference that after load model, FeedFroward takes 0MB memory before make one predict, but `mx.mod.Module` takes up memory once loaded, and increase obviously after making one prediction.

Comment: You should limit your question to 1, at a given time. Broad scope questions are flagged according to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MXNet imperative API Gluon and that will let you use different batch-sizes.

If like in this case, your model was trained using the symbolic API or has been exported in the serialized MXNet format ('-0001.params', '-symbol.json' for e.g), you can load it in Gluon that way:

```
ctx = mx.cpu()

sym = mx.sym.load_json(open('det1-symbol.json', 'r').read())
PNet = gluon.nn.SymbolBlock(outputs=sym, inputs=mx.sym.var('data'))
PNet.load_params('det1-0001.params', ctx=ctx)
```

Then you can use it the following way:

```
# a given batch size (1)
data1 = mx.nd.ones((1, C, W, H))
output1 = PNet(data1)

# a different batch size (5)
data2 = mx.nd.ones((5, C, W, H))
output2 = PNet(data2)
```

And it would work.

You can get started with MXNet Gluon with the official [60 minutes crash course](https://medium.com/apache-mxnet/mxnet-gluon-in-60-minutes-3d49eccaf266)

Comment: This helps me a lot, thanks! I will transfer to gluon API later!